# jmeter latency problem

Tags: jmeter

After deployment from the nightly build, the response time of logging into the page is sometimes very high (30mins to more than an hour). I know jsps need to be recompiled after redeployment. However, it only takes 5 secs to login through the browser. It'd be great if anyone has any advice. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When they updated code, did they modify anything on the login page? I would recommend re-recording the login process and compare to the original.  You may find your script points to the wrong server or is now missing a required parameter.